# Optimizing a recurisive fibonacci method.

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

I'm trying to optimize a fibonacci recurisve method so that it isn't as slow as the recursive method. The parameters of the these methods have to be as such. Whenever I run this it isn't giving me the result I need. Any suggestions on how to move forward would be helpful.

```
      public static long optimizedFib(int n)
      {
          long[] parameters = new long[3];
          for(int i =0; i < n;i++)
          {
             parameters[i] = 1;
          }
          return optimizedFib(n, parameters);
      }

public static long optimizedFib(int n, long[] parameters)
{
    if(n <= 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {   
    parameters[2] = parameters[1] + parameters[0];
    parameters[1] = parameters[0]; 
    parameters[0] = parameters[2];
    }
    return optimizedFib(n-1, parameters);
}
```

}

Comment: Let me guess--are you getting an array-index-out-of-bounds error?  Check the logic of the upper method carefully (the one that doesn't have a `parameters` parameter).

Comment: @ajb Sorry I have over seen that point because in the title OP is asking for "optimization".

Comment: Hint #2: Which `return` statement in the code will return a value other than 1, and how does it do so?

Answer (score 1):

First, you're blowing past the bounds of your array.  You define your array with a size of 3:

```
long[] parameters = new long[3];
```

Then you iterate to `n`

```
for(int i =0; i < n;i++)
{
    parameters[i] = 1;
}
```

You also initialize your values to `1`, which is incorrect.  Since you only use three indexes, and we need only the first index to be `1`, we can simply initialize the first index to `1` (the remaining values will default to `0`).

```
public static long optimizedFib(int n)
{
    long[] parameters = new long[3];
    parameters[0]=1;
    return optimizedFib(n, parameters);
}
```

Next, your recursive method never returned the result of the calculation (it only ever returned `1`).  To fix that, we recursively call `optimizedFib` then return the sum of `parameters[0]` and `parameters[1]`.

```
public static long optimizedFib(int n, long[] parameters)
{
    if(n <= 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(n <= 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        parameters[2] = parameters[1] + parameters[0];
        parameters[1] = parameters[0];
        parameters[0] = parameters[2];
        optimizedFib(n-1, parameters);
        return parameters[0] + parameters[1];
    }
}
```

**Note that you will overflow the `long` datatype when `n > 92`.**

### Additional Information

This optimization is called [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  You can see more implementations [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Fibonacci_Number_Program#Java).  There an iterative solution which, in my opinion, is a bit easier to grok:

```
public int fib(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    }
    int[] f = new int[n+1];
    f[0] = 0;
    f[1] = 1;
    for(int i = 2;i<=n;i++) {
        f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2];
    }
    return f[n];
}
```

[Source](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Fibonacci_Number_Program#Iterative_Memoized_version)